ML.Net prediction Showing 0 value always
My input and Output Models
public class MLInput
{
   
    public float[] Inputs { get; set; } // Handles any number of tags
    public float Value { get; set; }    // Target value
}

public class MLOutPut
{
    public float Prediction { get; set; }  // Predicted value
}

 Sample ML Input Objects

    [
 {"Inputs":[480.291077,535.2749,8.185375,5.358807],"Value":187.421143},
{"Inputs":[551.999756,548.0591,8.9576,4.947536],"Value":241.330811},
{"Inputs":[513.7134,562.307739,9.582937,4.62406254],"Value":173.898956},
{"Inputs":[495.53476,491.688538,9.700299,4.87886333],"Value":257.493927},
{"Inputs":[514.7245,489.179443,8.354404,5.158723],"Value":133.447586},
{"Inputs":[490.7611,450.309448,9.798013,4.991706],"Value":243.573013},
{"Inputs":[526.8138,441.718353,9.158744,5.07973528],"Value":297.033051},
{"Inputs":[551.9653,531.5339,8.307111,5.23646641],"Value":162.436508},
]

My Code is This
        MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
        var schemaDef = Microsoft.ML.Data.SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(MLInput));
        schemaDef["Inputs"].ColumnType = new Microsoft.ML.Data.VectorDataViewType(Microsoft.ML.Data.NumberDataViewType.Single, inputCount);
        
        IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(inputData,schemaDef);
        var trainTestData = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(dataView, testFraction: 0.2); // split fraction should be use here
        var trainingDataView = trainTestData.TrainSet;
        var testingDataView = trainTestData.TestSet;

        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", nameof(MLInput.Inputs)) // Concatenate all input features
                    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns("Label", "Value")) // Copy the target value to the Label column                            
                    .Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.Sdca(labelColumnName: "Label", featureColumnName: "Features", maximumNumberOfIterations: maxIterations)); // Use a regression algorithm

        
        
        var pre = dataView.Preview();
        var dta = trainingDataView.Preview();
        // Train the model
        var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);

        // Evaluate the model
        var predictions = model.Transform(testingDataView);
        var metrics = mlContext.Regression.Evaluate(predictions, labelColumnName: "Label");

        // Output evaluation metrics
        Console.WriteLine($"R^2: {metrics.RSquared}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Mean Absolute Error: {metrics.MeanAbsoluteError}");

        //Use the Model for Prediction
        
        var predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<MLInput, MLOutPut>(model, inputSchemaDefinition: schemaDef);

        var newData = new MLInput { Inputs = new float[] { 530.0f, 510.0f, 8.5f, 5.0f } };
        var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(newData);

        Console.WriteLine($"Predicted Value: {prediction.Prediction}");

My Predited Value is gining always 0 is there anything wrong please help me i am New to ML.Net I just now started working with the samples.

I don't know what language this is, but it's not Python or [tag:ml].

ML. NET With C# language
